# GAS フォームの質問タイプを変更したい

Tags: google-apps-script

GASにて　フォームの質問タイプを変更したい
現在テキスト入力になっているものを
プルダウン形式にしたい

可能でしょうか？
いろいろと探しましたが
見つけることが出来ませんでした

Comment: googleフォームでプルダウンリストを使う方法はありますが、スプレッドシートで使いたいのですか、どっちかわかりません。

Comment: スプレッドシートではなくフォームのほうです

Comment: フォームにてプルダウンリストを使いたい
というだけではなく
現在テキスト入力になっているものを
GASにてプルダウンリスト形式に変えたいという事です
新たに質問を作ると、転記されるスプレッドシートへの
データの列が狂ってしまいます
なので上記のようなことがしたいのです

Comment: このような記事がありました。https://qiita.com/miyabe-mitsuhiro/items/f1122f87a7d9b59ed69d#:~:text=%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0%E3%80%81%E3%80%8C%E4%BC%9A%E7%A4%BE%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92%E8%A8%98%E5%85%A5,%E9%A0%85%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%8C%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82

Comment: いや　そういう事じゃありません
単にプルダウンリストを作ったり　項目を編集したりするのは
わかりますが・・